# How do Android notifications get displayed?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I have been trying to figure out how android notifications get displayed but can seem to understand. I will really appreciate if someone explains it to me.

I am particularly interested in how notifications like that about wifi, Bluetooth is displayed because these notifications allow you to enter a reply in a textbox and click OK or SEND to reply to the notification. Here is the real question, do the handlers for the notifications come with the android os, or they get programmed by anyone who wants to use them?

What if I wanted to copy the message displayed by the notification and display it inside an application with a real textbox and OK button so that it won't pop up on the screen, for example instead of having a notification that pops up above the screen like

> Enter the code to pair Bluetooth
>       with Samsung Note II
>           OK

I want to have an application that will launch and display that notification in a window with a real button. The question is how can I do that?.

Sorry for being too clumsy, I will appreciate if someone can edit the question if there understand what I want to ask better. 
I want

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Hope this may help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough)